# Does 'digitization' of tickets always need private data? Or is it just data gathering? Any simple method without?

Tags: signature, authentication, protocol-design, data-privacy

Many companies argue their gathering of private data with 'digitization' but I guess their real intention is most likely just gathering data. However I didn't came up with a simple idea without it.

**Use case:** Digital ticket for an event or for transportation or similar. 
We have: a ticket Seller $S$, a ticket owner $O$ and multiple ticket verifier $V_i$. 
$V_i$ need to verify $O$ bought a digital ticket from $S$.

**Rules:**

- $S$ want to ensure a ticket is only used by a single person
- multiple $V_i$ are allowed to proof it multiple times
- neither $V_i$ or $S$ need to collect private data of $O$ (e.g. like the name or phone number), also not in encrypted form
- $O$ bought the ticket from $S$ before any approval from $V_i$ can happen
- during the approval $V_i$ and $O$ are located closely to each other in the real world
- does not require anything physical owned by $O$ except a smartphone (e.g. no paper ticket, no passport, no special device, ..)

**Question:** Is there any cryptographic method which can handle this?

---

(question has been edited, see history for more restrictive version)

Comment: If your ticket is copyable digital data, Alice can buy a ticket, give Bob a copy and both use the same ticket. The ticket needs extra info (Name, apperance, etc.) to prevent Bob from using Alice's ticket. Verifiers can detect impossible use patterns (EG:20 people use the same ticket to enter a building without leaving, use pattern implies very fast travel, ...) and reject impossible ticket uses. This still allows Alice or Bob (but not both) to use a ticket Alice purchased.

Comment: @RichardThiessen Thanks for reply. I had similar thoughts but had hope there is some better, more reliable way. I will modify the question to be less restrictive and more common. Maybe this allows some alternative answer.

Comment: Is O a honest player or a malicious player in the story? Are you trying to prevent others from stealing O's ticket & using it or are you trying to prevent O from giving out copies of his ticket to others to use?

Comment: @user93353 Similar to the real world: most O are honest but there are some malicious player O who are giving out copies of the ticket to other users (friends of O) and there are some malicious player who try to steal O's ticket without O knowing about it.

Comment: There are cryptographic ways of prevent malicious players from using O's ticket without his help but I don't think there is a way to stop O from being malicious without adding extra info

Comment: Much depends on how much you trust it's economically viable to hack a mobile phone to clone a ticket, and to what degree the $V_i$ can communicate to try to detect a cloned ticket.